# Where not null document=doctype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do -
Where doctype is not null (doctype=documenttype)

I had a look at the SQL on MSDN for not null and where clauses and i cannot seem to find anything. 
My last attempt was

```
where DocType is not null (f4111dt.DocType=f0911.documenttype)
```

---

But it is throwing up an error around f4111dt which is not an issue

If i just have where 4111dt.DocType=f0911dt.documenttype

then i lose the null values (which i want) which are in 4111dt.DocType because they do not match to anything in f0911dt.documenttype.

However if i dont have the statement 4111dt.DocType=f0911dt.documenttype
The document types wont match up...

Comment: Are you not just missing an `AND` so: `where DocType is not null AND (f4111dt.DocType=f0911.documenttype)`

Comment: Please explain what `Where doctype is not null (doctype=documenttype)` is intended to mean.

Comment: @DaveHogan - In that case just `f4111dt.DocType=f0911.documenttype` is sufficient as if `DocType` is `NULL` that will never be `true`

Comment: @MartinSmith - True! I should have been thinking `OR` but the question wasn't clear.

Comment: Your answer was correct for what i thought i wanted. Sometimes you have to just give it a go and see what you get back from what you think you need and then you relaise what you really need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are trying to bring also those where doctype is null:

```
Where DocType is null OR (f4111dt.DocType=f0911.documenttype)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has matched up my document types

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
where DocType is not null AND (f4111dt.DocType=f0911.documenttype)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although i stated this is what i wanted, this wasnt getting me the right results